# How can we generate a $2$-digit number $XY$ on base $B$, such that $BX+Y=Y^X$?

Tags: arithmetic, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

For example, $25$ on base $10$ is equal to $5^2$.

This should be pretty easy to solve using fairly simple arithmetic.

But I'm finding it hard to generate any other solutions besides the one mentioned above.

Comment: What makes you assume that this is easy to solve 'using fairly simple arithmetic'? Integer equations can generally be pretty hard problems.

Comment: @flawr: Well, it looks like a fairly simple diophantine equation. Am I wrong here?

Comment: As far as I know diophantine equations are polynomial equations in $\mathbb Z$. Pell's equation or fermats last theorem look pretty simple too but are far from trivial to solve. I do not even see how you could easily solve this equation in $\mathbb R$

Comment: @flawr: OK, so what's the terminology for equations that you are looking only for integer solutions to?

Comment: I'd just say 'integer equation' as far it is not a special type, but perhaps there is another word.

Comment: @flawr: The description of this tag here says "Questions on finding integer/rational solutions of equations". It doesn't specify that these equations are necessarily polynomials.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation and you will see that polynomial integer equations are referred to as diophantine. Here is a plot for your equation for $b=2$ and even in $\mathbb R^2$ the solutions seem not trivial: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FNDY3.png

Comment: @flawr: OK, thanks. Just a quick side-note on your logic: "polynomial integer equations are referred to as diophantine" doesn't imply that **all** diophantine are polynomial integer equations.

Comment: And 'are referred to' does not imply that the statement is true...

Comment: @flawr: Why is the down-vote for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two more specific solutions: $52_6=2^5$ and $73_{312}=3^7$.

I got both of these by solving your equation for the base $B$:  $B=\frac{Y^x-Y}{X}$.  You then need solutions where $B>X$.  One thing to note is that if $Y$ is prime, then $B$ works out to be an integer because of Euler's Theorem.

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!